# How to load database offline without internet

Tags: android

I'm working a Android project, we get infomations from API using JSON, it runs online it's okay, and now I would like to load database without internet (not wifi, 3G, 4G), and while there is internet again it will compare data and update new information.
Can you suggest me any solution  ?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the suggestion:

1. Always get data from API and save to database.
2. Always get data to show from database (both online and offline).